# ADVENT Vega tablet - USB Drivers

Tags: tablet, usb-drivers

I just got my hands on an old [ADVENT Vega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_Vega) tablet. All the download [links](http://adventcomputers.co.uk/product-download-select/285) in its official website are broken. I the file named USB System Driver. I can't find it anywhere else either. Every link I came across turns out to be broken.

Can anyone provide a healthy link to it?

The device seems to be forgotten. Any other files related to this device are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm is this the Nvidia based tablet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't wanna lie, your device support accessories are outdated. Its really difficult to find the official softwares for your device.

However after a bit of digging I found out its a bit of proceedure to get the instalation of your device drivers. Based on the following thread: [ADVENT VEGA USB DRIVER PROBLEM](http://www.modaco.com/forums/topic/343844-advent-vega-usb-driver-problem/)

You might need to find the two tools :

1. [AUDI - Automated USB Driver Installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/audiforvegacream2advent/)
2. [VegaTools](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=954434)

You need to  download the 97MB file (which include the tools, custom rom and **drivers**) Ignore the ROM files, we just need the USB drivers (containing `NvidiaUsb.inf" and the other has: androidwinusb86.cat, androidwinusba64.cat, android_winusb.inf` )
here: [r8-vega-update-modacocustomrom](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6wccmj3a8dg68m8/r8-vega-update-modacocustomrom-unsigned.zip)

Read full instructions here: [ADVENT VEGA USB DRIVER PROBLEM](http://www.modaco.com/forums/topic/337380-beta-audi-automated-usb-driver-installer/)

Credits:

[Vega clone USB drivers problem (and bootloop)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2202031)

Hope this works